# Reading an array of text fields

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtextfield

So I need to make a Java program that can read in user input in text-fields. I was able to set up the array of text fields but reading in the input and storing the data in a new array is troubling me greatly. I made a listener for the buttons and I just need to figure out how to store the information entered in the textField array into the grade array so I can perform calculations on the grades. I am new to this site and appreciate the help

```
//an Array for test scores and one to hold the input grades
  JTextField[] testScores;
  double[] grade;

/**
    Constructor
*/

public StatisticsCalculator()
{
    //Display a Title
    setTitle("JP Stearns");

    //Specify the action for the Close button
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create a Border Layout
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //Create the Custom Panels
    buildScoresPanel();
    buildStatisticsPanel();

    //Build the Button Panel
    buildButtonPanel();

    //Add the Components to the content pane
    add(scoresPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(statisticsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //Pack the contents of the Window to display it.
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

    //Create a GridLayout manger
    //with 1 row 4 columns.
    scoresPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4));

    //Create 4 text fields using an array
    testScores = new JTextField[4];

    for (int index = 0; index < testScores.length; index++)
        {
            testScores[index] = new JTextField(4);
            scoresPanel.add(testScores[index]);
        }

    //Border the panel
    scoresPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Test Scores"));

private void buildScoresPanel()
{
    //Create a panel for the test scores
    scoresPanel = new JPanel();

    //Create a GridLayout manger
    //with 1 row 4 columns.
    scoresPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4));

    //Create 4 text fields using an array
    testScores = new JTextField[4];

    for (int index = 0; index < testScores.length; index++)
        {
            testScores[index] = new JTextField(4);
            scoresPanel.add(testScores[index]);
        }

    //Border the panel.v
    scoresPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Test Scores"));
}
```

Comment: I don't see that you've posted your ActionListener and its actionPerformed method showing your attempt to solve this just yet. Please post this so we can see what you may be doing wrong and better understand your problem. Also please take care with your code formatting, using 4 spaces (no tabs) for each indentation and using regular consistent indentation for each level. This will greatly aid our understanding of your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think more information is needed, however it would look like you can do it 
something like this(psuedo code):

```
 JButton button = new JButton("This is L");
  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 

          for(int i=0; i<testScores.length(); i++)
                grade[i]=Double.parseDouble(testScores[i].getText());
                 //then do calculations like grade[i] * 100%
             }
```

Comment: I will give it a try when I get home from work thanks.